# Python: Replace all substring occurrences with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, replace

I would like to replace all substring occurrences with regular expressions. The original sentences would be like:

```
mystring = "Carl's house is big. He is asking 1M for that(the house)."
```

Now let's suppose I have two substrings I would like to bold. I bold the words by adding ** at the beginning and at the end of the substring. The 2 substrings are:

```
substring1 = "house", so bolded it would be "**house**"
substring2 = "the house", so bolded it would be "**the house**"
```

At the end I want the original sentence like this:

```
mystring = "Carl's **house** is big. He is asking 1M for that(**the house**)."
```

The main problem is that as I have several substrings to replace, they can overlap words like the example above. If I analyze the longest substring at first, I am getting this:

```
Carl's **house** is big. He is asking 1M for that(**the **house****).
```

On the other hand, if I analyze the shortest substring first, I am getting this:

```
Carl's **house** is big. He is asking 1M for that(the **house**).
```

It seems to be I will need to replace from the longest substring to the shortest, but I wonder how should I do to consider it in the first replacement but in the second. Also remember the substring can appear several times in the string.

Note:// Suppose the string ** will never occur in the original string, so we can use it to bold our words

Comment: [```re.sub()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) can take a function for the *repl* argument.  Create a pattern that matches your substrings, then create a function that takes a match object as an argument and returns that string modified however you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for all of the strings at once, so that the fact that one is a substring of another doesn't matter:

```
re.sub(r"(house|the house)", r"**\1**", mystring)
```

Comment: What does the `\1` mean? What does `|` mean?

Comment: @wwii `\1` refers the first matched group, `|` is a `or` operator that helps you have a pattern thats `house` `or` `the house`

Answer (score 1):

You could have a group that is not captured and is note required. If you look at the regex patter `(?P<repl>(?:the )?house)`, the `(?:the )?` part is saying that there might be a `the` in the string, if it is present, include it in the match. This way, you let the `re` library optimize the way it matches. Here is the complete example

```
>>> data = "Carl's house is big. He is asking 1M for that(the house)."
>>> re.sub('(?P<repl>(?:the )?house)', '**\g<repl>**', data) 
"Carl's **house** is big. He is asking 1M for that(**the house**)."
```

Note: `\g<repl>` is used to get all the string matched by the group `<repl>`

Answer (score 0):

You could do two passes:

First: Go through from longest to shortest and replace with something like:

- 'the house': 'AA_THE_HOUSE'
- 'house': 'BB_HOUSE'

Second: Go through replace like:

- 'AA_THE_HOUSE': '`**the house**`'
- 'BB_HOUSE': '`**house**`'

Answer (score 0):

Replace the strings with some unique values and then replace them back with original string enclosed in ** to make them bold.

For example:

'the house' with 'temp_the_house'
'house' with 'temp_house'

then 'temp_house' with '**house**' 
'temp_the_house' with '**the house****'

Should work fine. You can automate this by using two lists.